# Why do correlated decision trees increase bias?

Tags: cart, bias, bagging, bias-variance-tradeoff

To decrease variance in decision trees often, bagging is used to create several decision trees. This has better accuracy than one tree since the decrease in variance outweighs the increase in bias.

But bias does increase by a bit. As I understand it, it is because of:

1) You only take a subset of your training data to create your bagged models, thus within that model bias is higher (due to less data) and this happens for all the bagged models, so even when you take the average of their outputs, it will be more biased/further from the "truth".

2) When there are strong predictors for the output, your trees will look a like and thus be correlated (which can be corrected with Random Forest). However I do not see why these correlated trees increase my bias (this is my question).